# How and when to return values properly with promises in google cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, swift, google-cloud-functions

I'm slowly working my way through Node.js. I've got a basic iOS app (swift) that pushes a message to Firestore and I'm using Node to send a notification when the database is updated.

```
exports.updateRequestToJoin = functions.firestore
  .document('/chats/{chatId}')
  .onUpdate(event => {

    if(userId != sentBy)
    {
        return db.collection('users').doc(userId).get().then(doc => {

                var payload = {
                  notification:{
                    title: "msg",
                    body: "send msg"
                  }
                };

                admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcm_token, payload)
                .then(function(response) {
                 // See the MessagingDevicesResponse reference documentation for
                 // the contents of response.
                 console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                 console.log("Error sending message:", error);
                });

              };

  return 0
});
```

Initially, I just had `return` at the end of the function but was getting the error "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value" until I used `return 0` and that seemed to silence the error.

The things I was unsure about are:

1. Is returning a value like 0 ok practice?
2. When the error says "expected Promise or value" does the promise refer to the `.then`?
3. In the if statement, I return the db.collection - is that necessary to return that or can I skip the `return` keyword?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have good questions here. The place to start is with the function caller. You are exporting updateRequestToJoin(). What is the caller expecting? Are you thinking in terms of exiting the function with a success or failure code? Node apps tend to work differently than scripting environments that return only boolean values. The whole node ethos is about supporting a single thread environment that is happy to execute asynchronously. So, node functions tend either to return Promises, with their built-in resolve or reject methods; or they run a callback.

If you want to merely return a success code in your then statement, or a failure code in your catch statement, you could something as simple as this:

```
if(userId != sentBy)
{
    db.collection('users').doc(userId).get().then(doc => {

            var payload = {
              notification:{
                title: "msg",
                body: "send msg"
              }
            };

            admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcm_token, payload)
            .then(function(response) {
             // See the MessagingDevicesResponse reference documentation for
             // the contents of response.
             console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
             return true;
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
             console.log("Error sending message:", error);
             return false;
            });

          };
```

The success or failure is returned in the then/catch of your admin.messaging chain.

That's sort of the answer to your first question and a partial answer to your second. A more complete answer to your second question requires a bit of reading. [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) is a native Javascript object that gives you convenience methods to handle asynchronous execution. The db.collection chain you are calling, and the admin.messaging chain are Promises (or some sort of thenable construct) that are returning a resolve in the then, and a reject in the catch (you are not using the catch side of the db.collection call, but you are using the catch side of the admin.messaging call).

Finally, as to whether you need to return the db.collection chain, you would do this if the db.collection call was a part of a Promise.all execution of an array of function calls. In this case, however, it looks like you want to simply return a success or failure code, based on the success or failure of your admin.messaging call.

I am making some assumptions about your goal here. Hopefully, at least, this moves the discussion toward clarity.

Comment: Thanks for replying. And just to clarify does every then/catch have to return something? You can't just have statements execute in then/catch without a return? Also re: exports.updateRequestToJoin all I'm really after is cloud functions onUpdate method to execute when a specific field in the db is updated - is using "export" appropriate?

Comment: Then and catch statements do not have to return a value; they can merely do things. I would caution against that as a practice. Good application design has 2 objectives: elegant task execution and articulate messaging. Returning values from thenable functions can be an important part of messaging, which in turn supports the execution flow.

Regarding node module exports, node is meant to have one or more exported functions or classes in a module. That's how an imported (es6) or required module exposes its api.